# Why Scala classes cannot have parameter of type object in contructor?

Tags: java, scala, constructor

As far as I understood, `object` is simply singleton instance. I would like to create enumeration type with cell types, and then `class Cell` with constructor containing coordinates and enumeration type. However, it cannot be done, and I cannot find out why.

```
object CellType extends Enumeration {
  val Empty, X, O = Value
}
```

In another file:

```
class Cell(column: Int, row: Int, cellType : CellType) {
} // CellType is an object, and it doesn't work!
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it, or at least a reason why Scala forbids objects in contructors?

Error message:

> Warning:(3, 37) imported 'CellType' is permanently hidden by
>   definition of object CellType in package model import
>   de.htwg.model.CellType

Comment: Any error messages? Add them to the question please.

Comment: Good point! Message added in description

Comment: This error message comes from an added import (probably from auto-import feature of IDE) which misleads you as from where the issue comes. It is due to the fact that the IDE tries to import a type `CellType` since you are using this identifier has a type in your signature, while you already have such identifier as a value in your package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CellType` is not a type, it's an object. It is actually the only object of its type, `CellType.type`. If you want to have a function argument that can only be this object, you may use an argument of type `CellType.type`. But then, why even bother putting it as an argument, if it can only be `CellType`? Might as well use the object directly, not passing it as an argument.

What you probably want is not the type of `CellType`, but the type of its enumerated values, which happens to be `CellType.Value`.

NB: I personally found rather disturbing that the scala language defines on the same level `trait`s and `class`es, which are types, and `object`s, which are  instances of a singleton type. You should not be misguided by this apparent analogy, and really consider objects as values, and classes and traits as types.